# If $f$ is integrable on $[a,\ b]$ and $\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm dx >1$, then there exists a point $c$ in $(a,\ b)$ such that $f(c) > \frac{1}{b-a}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So far for this problem, to my understanding, for something to be integrable means that $U(p,\ f) - L(p,\ f) < \epsilon$ but not sure how exactly to move beyond there to show that there exists a point $c$ in $(a,\ b)$ such that $f(c) > \frac{1}{b - a}$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose not. Then $f(x)\leq1/(b-a)$ for all $x$. Then $$\int_a^bf(x)dx\leq\int_a^b\frac{1}{b-a}dx=1.$$
This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**:Suppose otherwise $f(x) \leq \dfrac{1}{b-a}, \forall x \in (a,b)$, then use the property: If $f, g \in \mathcal{R}[a,b],f \leq g \Rightarrow \displaystyle \int_{a}^b f dx \leq \displaystyle \int_{a}^b gdx$ to get a contradiction.